# Chainr.transform giving Null as transformedObject

Tags: java, json, jolt

I'm working on a requirement to convert JSONObject from one to another with the help of Jolt.

The source input i'm passing as :

```
{
  "a":"ABC",
  "b":"ABC1",
  "c":1,
  "d":2,
  "e":"ABC2",
  "details":
  {
    "a1": "ABC3",
    "b1": "ABC4",
    "c1": 3,
    "d1": "ABC5",
    "e1": "ABC6",
    "f1": "ABC7"
}
}
```

I need in form of

```
{
  "ConvertedOutput" : {
    "X1" : "ABC1",
    "Y1" : "ABC4"
  }
}
```

Spec i used :

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "b": "ConvertedOutput.X1",
      "details": {
        "b1": "ConvertedOutput.Y1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I'm able to get the proper output from  : https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception. But when i use same spec via code Chainr.transform returning null.

Code part

```
List<Object> transformJsonSpec = JsonUtils.classpathToList("inputSpecJSONPath");
final Chainr chainr = Chainr.fromSpec(transformJsonSpec);
Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(payload);
System.out.println("transformSpec  Str " + transformJsonSpec.toString());
System.out.println("transformSpec " + transformJsonSpec);
System.out.println("transformedOutput " + transformedOutput);
System.out.println(" jolt transform " + JsonUtils.toJsonString(transformedOutput));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload needs to be converted using `JsonUtils.jsonToObject` if you are passing in a `String`:

```java
Object transformedOutput = chainr.transform(JsonUtils.jsonToObject(payload));
```